# Python Pandas: how to assign a sequence of numbers as a column based off a filter?

Tags: python, pandas, list, time-series

I am attempting to assign a sequential list of numbers as a column based off a filter to a dataframe of work times called `work`; the purpose is to produce a unique id tied to every start of a gig. Below is the original set with a `gig_status column` that shows when a gig starts for a worker in a vehicle:

```
   worker   veh   gig_status               starttime                stoptime
0  11133y  QQUK1     start            2018-12-21 15:17:29     2018-12-21 15:18:57
1  44706h  FF243     start            2019-01-01 00:10:16     2019-01-01 00:16:32
2  44706h  FF243                      2019-01-01 00:27:11     2019-01-01 00:31:38
3  44706h  FF243                      2019-01-01 00:46:20     2019-01-01 01:04:54
4  44761y  LL525     start            2019-01-01 00:19:06     2019-01-01 00:39:43
5  44842q  OO454     start            2019-01-01 00:12:35     2019-01-01 00:19:09
6  44842q  OO454                      2019-01-01 00:47:55     2019-01-01 01:00:01
7  44842q  OO454                      2019-01-01 01:12:47     2019-01-01 02:01:50
8  46090u  OP324     start            2019-01-01 00:16:23     2019-01-01 00:39:46
9  46090u  OP324                      2019-01-01 00:58:02     2019-01-01 01:19:02
```

Here is what I expect the initial output to be:

```
   worker       veh    gig_status          starttime                stoptime.      gig_id
0  11133y      QQUK1     start         2018-12-21 15:17:29     2018-12-21 15:18:57    1
1  44706h      FF243     start         2019-01-01 00:10:16     2019-01-01 00:16:32    2
2  44706h      FF243                   2019-01-01 00:27:11     2019-01-01 00:31:38   
3  44706h      FF243                   2019-01-01 00:46:20     2019-01-01 01:04:54
4  44761y      LL525     start         2019-01-01 00:19:06     2019-01-01 00:39:43    3
5  44842q      OO454     start         2019-01-01 00:12:35     2019-01-01 00:19:09    4
6  44842q      OO454                   2019-01-01 00:47:55     2019-01-01 01:00:01    
7  44842q      OO454                   2019-01-01 01:12:47     2019-01-01 02:01:50    
8  46090u      OP324     start         2019-01-01 00:16:23     2019-01-01 00:39:46    5
9  46090u      OP324                   2019-01-01 00:58:02     2019-01-01 01:19:02
```

The idea is then to use a fill forward to tie each record to its new id.

In `R` using `data.table()` this is simple and written out something like this:

```
work[gig_status=="start", gig_id:=seq.Int(.N)]
```

Basically a sequence is assigned to every record that fits the "start" value in gig_status.

How would I achieve this output in python? I have tried using range but it doesn't seem to work the same way:

```
#produce the length of the subset dataframe
x = len(work.loc[work.gig_status == 'start'])

#produce a listed range from 0 to that length and assign as a new column
work['gig_id'] = work.loc[work.gig_status == 'start'] = list(range(0,x)
```

I end up with a gig_id that is not between 0 and the length of the filtered data set.

Comment: the empty spaces in gig_status are NaN's or empty character `''` or `' '` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `cumsum()` and `mask()`:

```
df['gig_id']=df['gig_status'].eq('start').cumsum().mask(df['gig_status'].isna())
#OR via where() but with opposite condition
df['gig_id']=df['gig_status'].eq('start').cumsum().where(df['gig_status'].notna())
```

OR

via `loc` accessor and `cumsum()`:

```
m=df['gig_status'].eq('start')
df.loc[df['gig_status'].notna() & m,'gig_id']=m.cumsum()
```

OR

```
#import numpy as np
df['gig_id']=np.where(df['gig_status'].isna(),np.nan,df['gig_status'].eq('start').cumsum())
```